# RestKit - Sending POST & Receive Response mapped

Tags: objective-c, rest, jersey, restkit, restkit-0.20

So, i m using RestKit version 0.20 and i m successfully sending a POST request as JSON. My Server backend (Java REST WS (Jersey)) is mapping everything right, aswell Restkit.

My Problem is now that i m sending a different Object back as that I have Post. I have following mapping setup in RestKit:

```
- (void)createUserAccount:(DeviceDTO *)devDTO :(UserDTO *)userDTO block:(void (^)(id))block{
    id errorCode __block;
    // Configure a request mapping for our Article class. We want to send back title, body, and publicationDate
    RKObjectMapping* deviceRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [deviceRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"model", @"name", @"systemName", @"systemVersion", @"devToken" ]];

    RKObjectMapping* msRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [msRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"validSince", @"validTill" ]];

    RKObjectMapping* countryRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [countryRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"idNumberDTO", @"iso2DTO", @"short_nameDTO", @"calling_codeDTO" ]];

    RKObjectMapping* contactsRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [contactsRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"fullName", @"phoneNumber"]];

    RKObjectMapping* userRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [userRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"displayName", @"phoneNumber", @"status", @"userID", @"realName" ]];

    [userRequestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"deviceInfo" toKeyPath:@"device" withMapping:deviceRequestMapping]];
    [userRequestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"memberShipDetails" toKeyPath:@"memberShip" withMapping:msRequestMapping]];
    [userRequestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"country" toKeyPath:@"country" withMapping:countryRequestMapping]];
    [userRequestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"contacts" toKeyPath:@"contacts" withMapping:contactsRequestMapping]];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:userRequestMapping objectClass:[UserDTO class] rootKeyPath:nil];


    //Create Objects
    UserDTO *user = [[UserDTO alloc]init];
    ..........

    DeviceDTO *device = [[DeviceDTO alloc]init];
    ..........

    user.deviceInfo = device;

    MemberShipDTO *ms = [[MemberShipDTO alloc]init];
    .......

    user.memberShipDetails = ms;



    RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ErrorMapping class]];
    [errorMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"errorCode", @"errorMessage" ]];

    RKObjectMapping* deviceRespMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[DeviceDTO class]];
    [deviceRespMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"model", @"name", @"systemName", @"systemVersion", @"devToken" ]];

    RKObjectMapping* msRespMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MemberShipDTO class]];
    [msRespMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"validSince", @"validTill" ]];

    RKObjectMapping* contactsRespMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ContactDTO class]];
    [contactsRespMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"fullName", @"phoneNumber"]];

    RKObjectMapping* userRespMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[UserDTO class]];
    [userRespMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"displayName", @"phoneNumber", @"status", @"userID", @"realName" ]];

    [userRespMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"deviceInfo" toKeyPath:@"device" withMapping:deviceRespMapping]];
    [userRespMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"memberShipDetails" toKeyPath:@"memberShip" withMapping:msRespMapping]];
    [userRespMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"country" toKeyPath:@"country" withMapping:countryRequestMapping]];
    [userRespMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"contacts" toKeyPath:@"contacts" withMapping:contactsRespMapping]];

    [errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"user" toKeyPath:@"user" withMapping:userRespMapping]];

    RKResponseDescriptor *errorDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/json"];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:errorDescriptor];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:user path:@"user/integrate" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
        NSArray* statuses = [mappingResult array];
        NSLog(@"Loaded statuses: %@", statuses);
        errorCode = [statuses objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"errorCode == %@", errorCode);
        block(errorCode);
        RKLogInfo(@"Load collection of Articles: %@", mappingResult.array);
    }failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        block(nil);
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
    }];

}
```

My JSON on my request is fine & the response is also fine:

```
{
    "errorMessage": null,
    "errorCode": 190,
    "user": {
        "displayName": "Saif",
        "phoneNumber": "+xxx",
        "userID": "xxx",
        "country": {
            "idNumberDTO": 83,
            "short_nameDTO": "Germany",
            "calling_codeDTO": "+49",
            "iso2DTO": "DE"
        },
        "device": {
            "devToken": "xxx",
            "model": "iPhone",
            "name": "Saifs iPhone",
            "systemName": "iPhone OS",
            "systemVersion": "6.1.4",
            "id": null
        },
        "memberShip": {
            "validSince": 1376047810000,
            "validTill": 1407583810000,
            "id": null
        },
        "contacts": [
            {
                "fullName": "xxx",
                "phoneNumber": "xxx"
            },
            {
                "fullName": "xxx",
                "phoneNumber": "xxx"
            },
            ....,
            ....,
            ....
        ],
        "id": null
    }
}
```

On my RK methode i get on this line:

```
    errorCode = [statuses objectAtIndex:0];
```

this Error:

```
2013-08-09 13:30:12.246 xxx![19310:440f] W restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:99 Adding mapping error: Expected an object mapping for class of type 'UserDTO', provider returned one for 'ErrorMapping'
2013-08-09 13:30:12.247 xxx![19310:440f] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:250 POST 'http://192.168.2.115:8080/WAZZUUPWS/rest/service/user/integrate' (200 OK / 0 objects) [request=1.3406s mapping=0.0047s total=1.3461s]
2013-08-09 13:30:12.249 xxx![19310:907] Loaded statuses: (
)
2013-08-09 13:30:12.250 xxx![19310:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

**It looks like the response couldnt be mapped and thats why the Resultarray is empty. Any idea how i can map a complex object from a response?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Restkit documentation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#handling-multiple-root-objects-in-core-data-postput):

*By default when postObject or putObject are used, RestKit is automatically going to try to map the JSON result into the sourceObject that was posted.*

In your code, you are posting an UserDTO instance and receiving a JSON response that should map to ErrorMapping. Hence, you are getting RKMappingErrorTypeMismatch from Restkit.

As explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#handling-multiple-root-objects-in-core-data-postput), instead of using post, you can create an RKRequestOperation yourself and nil the target object to override the defaults.

```
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:user
                                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                                              path:@"user/integrate"
                                                                                                        parameters:nil];
operation.targetObject = nil;

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    DLog(@"integrated user: %@", mappingResult.firstObject);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    DLog(@"error integrating user: %@", user);
}];
```

However, if you can modify the backend, I'd prefer to change the returned JSON. Instead of including the error codes in the JSON response, use relevant (HTTP) response status codes and include only domain model specific entities in your responses.

Comment: Mhh. Could you maybe try to give a example for RKRequestOperation??

Comment: -.- was trying the whole time like this [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];

Comment: Sry i was a little bit fast. I copypaste your sample code but the operation didnt have been posted. I updated your code to complete your answer.

Comment: [operation start]; was missing